# Import Swift class created dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am experimenting with a piece of code and I need some assistance. I am creating a file that is a swift file that contains a class and a variable. I am able to successfully create and read the file. Now, is it possible for my to use this swift file and access its variable (v, in this case)?

```
func writeF() {

    let file = "Sample.swift"
    let text =  "import Foundation \n" +
                "public class Sample { \n" +
                "   let v: Int = 0 \n" +
                "}"

    if let dir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first {
        let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: dir).URLByAppendingPathComponent(file)

        //writing
        do {
            try text.writeToURL(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        }
        catch {print("error writing file")}

        //reading
        do {
            let text2 = try NSString(contentsOfURL: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print(text2)
        }
        catch {

            print("error reading file")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that is why you compile your code :)

Comment: So no .. lol :) .. thats the end of this experiment. Thank you.

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve? any changing methods at runtime i know is swizzling

Answer (score 1):

You can't add code on runtime. When your code is compiled, there are no *.swift files left, that can be read by humans. After compiling, your code is basically `0` and `1` only.

Answer (score 0):

As FelixSFD said in their answer, you cannot dynamically build a Swift file and compile it at runtime on the device, at least not in the normal Sandboxed environment.  If you have a Jailbroken device, you can build and install the Swift open source runtime and compile programs on-the-fly that way.

As an alternative, you could look into the JavaScriptCore framework to build and run dynamic JavaScript code, and bridge it into your app.

Here's a quick example of passing an object to JavaScript and returning the same object with a class mapping:

```
import JavaScriptCore

let js = "function test(input) { return input }"

class TestClass: NSObject {
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

let context = JSContext()
context.evaluateScript(js)

let testFunc = context.objectForKeyedSubscript("test")
let result = testFunc.callWithArguments([TestClass(name: "test")])
result.toDictionary()

let testObj = result.toObjectOfClass(TestClass.self) as? TestClass
testObj?.name // "test"
```